# libcurl - можно ли посмотреть заголовки запроса?

Tags: c, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли, как то в Libcurl - посмотреть, какой заголовок был сформирован при запросе на сервер ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под рукой сейчас curl нету, а делается то что тебе надо через.

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace_funtion);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA, &config);
```

- https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
- https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html